# CosmosDB ReadOnly Keys throws authorization error

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have tried to read the documents from the `CosmosDb collection` using `Primary Key` and `Primary Read Only Key` using the below code.

```
    DocumentClient _documentRUClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndPointURI), PrimaryKey);
    DocumentClient _documentRClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndPointURI), 
                                                          ReadOnly_PrimaryKey);

    var result = _documentRUClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>
                (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DataBaseId, CollectionId), 
                new FeedOptions() { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).AsEnumerable().ToList();

    var result2 = _documentRClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>
                (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DataBaseId, CollectionId), 
                new FeedOptions() { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

The `DocumentClient` which uses the `Primary Key` retrieves the documents from Cosmos DB collection without any issues. But the one which uses the `Primary Read Only Key` throws the following error.

> The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check
>   that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the
>   key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get
>
> sat, 03 mar 2018 06:47:04 gmt
>
> ' ActivityId: d57786a0-f7a0-46e9-9375-d5251b81b1e3,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.108.4,
>   documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.20.2 Host/64-bit
>   MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.16299.0

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the complete error message. The payload is cut off.

Comment: @GauravMantri. Updated the question with complete error message.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Have you checked the key? Any progress?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Hi,any updates now?

Comment: @JayGong. Right now we are working with RW Keys. I'll check and give you the updates soon.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar ok.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue when I set the wrong Read-Only key.

***Sample code:***

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DocumentClient client;

        static string endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";

        static string key1 = "***";

        static string DataBaseId = "db";
        static string CollectionId = "coll";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key1);

            var result = client.CreateDocumentQuery
                (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DataBaseId, CollectionId),
                new FeedOptions() { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }).AsEnumerable().ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("aaa");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

***return message:***

[image]

I suggest you catch messages via Fiddler and check if your read-only key is correct.

Hope it helps you.